# VLOOKUP not suitable, how to get information when required item is not in 1st column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel table:

| Code | Name | Surname | State | Color | CW | Country | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XX12345 | John | Doe | MI | Blue | CW 2 | USA | 1990 |
| XX122222 | Jack | Gray | CA | Blue | CW 2 | USA | 1990 |
| YZ55567 | Pete | Norman | C | Yellow | CW 2 | USA | 1992 |
| JJ38459 | Mike | Grilly | CA | Green | CW 5 | USA | 1993 |
| JZ11111 | Yoshi | Puller | CA | Red | CW 7 | USA | 1993 |

In a seperate excel tab I want to create a table which shows only the content which meets a specific requirement. I want only those entrys to show, which are in the current calendar week.

I want to use a cell, where i can input for example **CW 7** and only the entry with **CW 7** appears.

I cannot re-arrange the columns so I guess Vlookup is not working?

The end goal is to create a table in the second excel tab which looks like this:

| Code | Name | Comment 1 | Comment 2 | Comment 3 | CW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JZ11111 | John |  |  |  | CW 7 |

So in the final table I want the **Code**, **Name** the **CW** and 3 blank fields.

Can I approach this w/o Visual Basic and just using simple excel functions? I read about INDEX() but don't really understand, how I would use it for this problem.

Thanks for your help
Pat

Comment: If your range of data is in `A1:H6` then this will work:  `=FILTER($A$2:$H$6,$F$2:$F$6="CW 7")` or if it's in a table: `=FILTER(Table1,Table1[CW]="CW 7")`

Comment: Why the CW 7 and return the Name is John but not the Yoshi?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to this. My preferred option is to use a combination of [INDEX()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) and [MATCH()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd). From what you describe, you want to return some data from a single row based on matching a value from one of the columns. Start with the `MATCH()` function:

```
=MATCH(A1,Sheet1!F:F,0)
```

... except `A1` is whatever cell where you've input the CW value you want and `Sheet1!F:F` is a reference to the column in your original table with all the CW values. This will either give you a number (indicating which row has the value) or an error (if the value wasn't found). Now you can pull other data from that row with something like this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,$A$2)
```

... except `Sheet1!A:A` is a reference to the column you want to pull data from and `A2` is whatever cell has the `MATCH()` formula in it. Index will look at that column and pull the n<sup>th</sup> item from that list based on the result of the match. Copy that formula for your other two columns and update the column reference appropriately.

---

You don't have to have a separate cell with the `MATCH()` value in it but it's *technically* computationally faster. You could combine them both like this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!F:F,0))
```

---

You can also use [XLOOKUP()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) in a very similar manner. It looks for a value in a range then returns the corresponding value from a different range. For example:

```
=XLOOKUP($A$1,Sheet1!F:F,Sheet1!A:A,"(CW not found)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the following various ways. They all first create a virtual table that fits your desired structure, then select the row array that matches the lookup value.

*Unfortunate aspect of them:  I set them up as a lookup using a cell, A1, to hold the lookup value. In looking at the question again before composing this answer, it looks (rather obviously, in retrospect) that the first column would be populated by, say, a listing of the first column's contents, or perhaps such a listing run through `UNIQUE()`. So each of these needs edited to not include the first column. Two parts to that and then a last change:  removal of any reference in them to cells C1:C3 as that is the first column and then changing the array constants used to pull the desired columns in the inside portions to account for the change in the set of columns. So `{1,2,7,7,7,6}` would become `{1,6,6,6,5}`. Etc. Finally, one would change the A1 as the lookup value to the cell reference for the first cell in the row.*

So, any of the following four formulas work, all following the same idea:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,C1:I3,{1,2,7,7,7,6},FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP(A1,C1:I3,{1,2,7,7,7,6},FALSE))

=IF(INDEX(C1:I3,MATCH(A1,C1:C3,0),{1,2,7,7,7,6})="","",INDEX(C1:I3,MATCH(A1,C1:C3,0),{1,2,7,7,7,6}))

=IF(XLOOKUP(A1,C1:C3,INDEX(C1:I3,SEQUENCE(3),{1,2,7,7,7,6}))="","",XLOOKUP(A1,C1:C3,INDEX(C1:I3,SEQUENCE(3),{1,2,7,7,7,6})))

=VLOOKUP(A1,IFERROR(INDEX((C1:C3,D1:D3,I1:I3,I1:I3,I1:I3,H1:H3),SEQUENCE(3),0,{1,2,7,7,7,6}),""),SEQUENCE(1,6),FALSE)
```

The three empty columns are, of course, the complication. That is why one builds the virtual (used on in actual calculation, and does not occur anywhere in the spreadsheet so no helper columns or Named Ranges).

All perfectly functional, but I kind of have an attachment to the first, because `VLOOKUP()` is as old a friend as `IF()` and `=`, and the fourth, because I like how it uses the fourth parameter (AREA) in `INDEX()` to make a table out of disparate and not necessarily contiguous ranges. That last will go away over the next year and a half as MS eventually lets the hoi polloi have access to the new functions for creating real arrays directly, so showing here gives me an odd pleasure. It also has the feature of being pretty extensible and the non-contiguous and the ability to use a cell range as more than one column which are both nice. (`INDEX()` lets one do the last for the rows and columns parameters too, but no one really does it much.)

I also think the first is the most direct and that means easier to understand and maintain in a year or two.